# What does [decl.constexpr].5 mean exactly?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, constexpr, constexpr-function

The standard on *constexpr functions* states under point 5 of [decl.constexpr]:

> *For a non-template, non-defaulted constexpr function or a non-template, non-defaulted, non-inheriting constexpr constructor, if no argument values exist such that an invocation of the function or constructor could be an evaluated subexpression of a core constant expression (5.19), the program is ill-formed; no diagnostic required.*

It goes on to give the following example for this:

```
constexpr int f(bool b){ return b ? throw 0 : 0; }  // OK
constexpr int f() { return f(true); }               // ill-formed, no diagnostic required
```

What I take from this is that functions with empty argument lists are no-diagnostic ill-formed. This strikes me as *extremely bizarre*, such that I suspect that my understanding is incorrect. For instance, would this also be ill-formed:

```
constexpr int g() { return 0; }       // ill-formed?
```

**If so, what is the rationale behind this, and if not what does the qualification mean / when does a constexpr function become ill-formed?**

---

Presumably the following are fine?

```
constexpr int h(int x) { return x; }  // presumably fine?
constexpr int l = h(42);              // also fine
```

Comment: This is sparked by this [chat discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215752/discussion-between-holyblackcat-and-bitmask). I suppose other people can join that chat.

Comment: There are similar rules about template which should have potential type/parameter for which it is instantiable (forbidding `static_assert(false);`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rationale for this rule is that there should be *at least one* context where the function can be evaluated in a `constexpr` context. e.g. given:

```
constexpr int f(bool b){ return b ? throw 0 : 0; }  // OK
constexpr int f() { return f(true); }               // ill-formed, no diagnostic required
```

There is no way to invoke `f()` in a `constexpr` context, since *all* paths through this function will end in an expression that is not a *core constant expression*.

A compiler would have to evaluate *all* possible calls to see if there is any way the function is usable in a `constexpr` context. This is not easily diagnosable in general, so the language says it's *ill-formed-no-diagnostic-required*, i.e. you've done something wrong, but the compiler can't diagnose it.

Note that if the zero argument overload of `f` was the following:

```
constexpr int f() { return f(false); }   // ok
```

that would be perfectly fine, since the evaluation ends in a *core-constant-expression*.

Similarly, this function:

```
constexpr int g() { return 0; }      // ok
```

as well as this one:

```
constexpr int h(int x) { return x; }  // ok
constexpr int l = h(42);              // ok
```

are fine, since `g` and `h` can be invoked in a `constexpr` context.

The wording of *"... if no argument values exist such that ..."* might be confusing, as you've asked about the well-formedness of `g`. But `g` can be invoked with zero arguments, or in other words, with a `void` argument, so it's fine.

Comment: So, if one were to remove the `throw` in the original example it'd be ok again, correct?

Comment: Yes, and it would be fine if the `bool` overload is invoked with an argument of `false` as well.

Comment: @bitmask - Well, that depends on what you replace it *with*.

Comment: Added that to the answer. And yes, you need to replace `throw` with a core-constant-expression for the call to `f(true)` to be ok.